# Is it better to use translate(-50px) or position absolute when i want to overlap a certain div over another element above it

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-position

So I'm making a simple contact page in which I've embedded a Google map below which the contact form comes.
I want the contact form to overlap over the map partially for which I used the `translate` property. This gave me a lot of white space below the contact form
Is it better to use `position` property and position the div using the bottom(-50%)

Here's the end result:
[Design sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Oye.png)

Here's the code I've used for making this:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3887.006558821487!2d77.64416197585778!3d13.035254113477981!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bae17afb2cfc539%3A0x22393ad17d784b40!2sSpydernet%20Technologies%20-%20Digital%20Marketing%2C%20SEO%2C%20Web%20Design%2C%20Web%20Development%20Company%20in%20Bangalore%2C%20Graphics%20Design!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1705463481649!5m2!1sen!2sin"
  width="100%"
  height="600"
  style="border: 0"
  allowfullscreen=""
  loading="lazy"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
></iframe>
<div class="map-section-container flex justify-center items-center   -translate-y-52 h-fit">
  <div class="contact-form w-[60%] bg-white drop-shadow-2xl text-center p-10 rounded-lg">
    <h2 class="text-black text-4xl font-[700] mb-3">Contact Form</h2>
    <p class="mb-7">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed
      tristique metus proin id lorem odio
    </p>
    <div class="contact-text1 text-left flex justify-evenly mb-7">
      <div class="text-field w-[30%]">
        <label for="name" class="block text-lg font-semibold"
          >Your Name</label
        >
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Your Name"
          class="rounded-md w-[100%] h-10 p-5 placeholder:text-lg text-lg border-solid border border-[#E5E5EA] "
        />
      </div>

      <div class="text-field w-[30%]">
        <label for="email" class="block text-lg font-semibold">Email</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          class="rounded-md w-[100%] h-10 p-5 placeholder:text-lg text-lg border-solid border border-[#E5E5EA] "
        />
      </div>

      <div class="text-field w-[30%]">
        <label for="phone" class="block text-lg font-semibold">Phone</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="phone"
          name="phone"
          placeholder="Phone"
          class="rounded-md w-[100%] h-10 p-5 placeholder:text-lg text-lg border-solid border border-[#E5E5EA] "
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-field w-[100%] text-left flex justify-center mb-7">
      <div class="message-cente w-[95%]">
        <label for="message" class="block text-lg font-semibold"
          >Message</label
        >
        <textarea
          type="text"
          id="message"
          name="message"
          class="rounded-md w-[100%] p-5 placeholder:text-lg text-lg h-56 border-solid border border-[#E5E5EA] "
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container-contact w-[97.5%] float-right">
      <a href="#"
        ><div
          class="contact-button flex justify-center items-center p-5 rounded-xl bg-[#FFA920] w-52 hover:bg-[#ffa920ae] transition-all duration-200"
        >
          Send Request
        </div></a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Relative positioning would still leave empty space below, and absolute positioning would take the element out of the flow. The best option would probably simply be a negative margin-top - at least if you _don't_ need it to be in percent (that would get problematic, because margins in percent always refer to the element's _width_.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:grid` on the parent of the map and contact form would allow you to create the overlap pretty easily. Something like this (I've removed lots of code for brevity):

```
<div class="parent">
    <iframe class="map"></iframe>
    <div class="contact-form"></div>
</div>

.parent {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: auto 50px auto; // 50px is the height of overlap - change as required
   // other styles as required
}

.map {
   grid-row: 1/span 2;
   // other styles as required
}

.contact-form {
   grid-row: 2/span 2
}
```